# How to enable bzip2 support in PHP 7

Tags: php, bzip2

I have an application that needs bzip2 support. I have installed the library, but I can't figure out how to enable it. By default it's disable in PHP.

I have searched the internet the whole day, but I can't get it to work. I am running on Debian 8 (Jeezy) and PHP 7. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Without knowing *what exactly* you are trying to do it's hard to tell how to achieve this. Anyway, what did *you* do to solve your problem?

Comment: I didn't, but I ended up purchase another vps with cPanel, which has a current php version and it came with bzip2 enabled, as well as other libraries (curl, dp, unzip, etc). The host that I had didn't support IPv6 and I have to have IPv6, so it worked out fine with the new host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the PHP manual, the bzip2 extension is not enabled by default (as you stated)

> Bzip2 support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to use the --with-bz2[=DIR] configuration option when compiling PHP to enable bzip2 support.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/bzip2.installation.php)

According to this quote you'll have to *compile* PHP by yourself in order to enable bzip2 support. Surely there are plenty of resources on the net on how to compile PHP (e.g. [here](http://www.web-tech-india.com/articles/php/compiling_php_apache)). Anyway, compiling it by yourself may not be suitable for a beginner like you are. You can surely give it a shot (you'll learn a lot), but it'll be **way** easier, if you have access to some kind of Linux expert.

Comment: Thanks! I completely didn't understand about compiling PHP, but your link pointed me in the right direction. I didn't want to mess with my current php setup so I didn't see the significance of that little instruction by php.net.

Answer (score 12):

u can simply install it.

```
apt install php7.0-bz2
```